# XSLT: different values for same namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

My input XML is as follows:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns0:PartyInfo xmlns:ns0="http://www.google.com/"> 
             <name xmlns="">John</name> 
        </ns0:PartyInfo> 
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>

    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns0:OperationRequest xmlns:ns0="http://www.yahoo.com"> 
            <name xmlns="">Mary</name> 
        </ns0:OperationRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

1) First problem: in my XSLT, I can only declare on value for my "ns0" namespace, so I can only access one of the nodes. How can I access them both (preferably in the same xslt file)?

2) Suppose I declare

```
xmlns:ns0="http://www.google.com"
```

Then the "John" string is output with extra characters:

[image]

I can use normalize-space to fix this, but it doesn't seem right.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show us the XSLT? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace prefix you use in the XSLT code doesn't have to be the same as the prefix used in the source document. It's only the URI that needs to match. So in your XSLT, simply bind different prefixes to the two namespace URIs.

Comment: I didn't find that to work.  I'm using Saxon and if the input contains

 `<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss" >`

And I use:
`<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
                xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
                xmlns:rssBoardMedia="http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss">`

then rssBoardMedia:description does not properly match to their media:description

Comment: @simpleCoder The answer is correct: there's a bug in your code, and if you show us your code then we can help you find it. Please submit a new question giving full details of what you did.

Comment: I posted a new one here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57616948/how-to-have-the-same-xslt-namespace-with-different-uris