# How to have the same XSLT namespace with different URIs?

Tags: xslt, rss, xslt-2.0, xml-namespaces

I am building an RSS parser that takes in the media namespace's items.

Example 1:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <channel>
        <title>Some channel</title>
        <item>
            <guid>234wwerwe</guid>
            <title>Some title</title>
            <media:description>test description 1</media:description>
            <pubDate>Tue, 30 Jul 2019 19:24:00 +0000</pubDate>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Example 2:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss">
    <channel>
        <title>Some second channel</title>
        <item>
            <guid>234wwsdflkjl23we</guid>
            <title>Some other title</title>
            <media:description>test description 2</media:description>
            <pubDate>Tue, 30 Jul 2019 19:24:00 +0000</pubDate>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I would like to convert this using the same xsl file but if I do something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:boardMedia="http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
            <item>
             <xsl:element name="referenceId">
                    <xsl:value-of select="guid" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="title">
                    <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="description">
                    <xsl:value-of select="media:description" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="boardMedia:description" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="itemPublishDate"><xsl:value-of select="pubDate" /></xsl:element>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then it only successfully pulls the description for the first rss, not the second.

Any suggestions on how to do this in one xsl file?

Comment: *"it only successfully pulls the description for the first rss, not the second.*" I don't think so: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1yan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, the problem cannot be reproduced using your code.

Note that you could simplify your code significantly:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/rss">
    <xsl:for-each select="channel/item">
        <item>
            <referenceId>
                <xsl:value-of select="guid" />
            </referenceId>
            <title>
                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            </title>
            <description>
                <xsl:value-of select="*:description" />
            </description>
            <itemPublishDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="pubDate" />
            </itemPublishDate>
        </item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1yan/1

Comment: interesting,  it might work in this limited case but I'm concerned about side-effects.

Comment: The only possible side effect is including `description` nodes from namespaces you **don't** want. If you're worried about that, then just list all allowed namespace as you have done. There is no reason why this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to merge these two `description` elements with your XSLT, you can try the following stylesheet (naming your second XML file `example_2.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" 
xmlns:boardMedia="http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss">
    <xsl:variable name="file2" select="document('example_2.xml')" />   <!-- Added to include the second file -->

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
            <item>
             <xsl:element name="referenceId">
                    <xsl:value-of select="guid" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="title">
                    <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="description">
                    <xsl:value-of select="media:description" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="$file2/rss/channel/item/boardMedia:description" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="itemPublishDate"><xsl:value-of select="pubDate" /></xsl:element>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Its result** is rather odd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:boardMedia="http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss">
    <referenceId>234wwerwe</referenceId>
    <title>Some title</title>
    <description>test description 1test description 2</description>
    <itemPublishDate>Tue, 30 Jul 2019 19:24:00 +0000</itemPublishDate>
</item>
```

But that seems to be the result you like.

Comment: I think you misundersand.  I want a single xsl file that can be ran on either of the xml files to produce results.  currently, I can only produce results for one xml, not the other.